# How to create a class that can inherit from either of two different classes?

Tags: oop, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I am looking for a way to design a `TSpeaker` that might be based on `TBose` class or might be based on a `TSonos` class.
Is this generally possible in Delphi today? What are the mechanisms I should look for?

Comment: Maybe a `TSpeaker` can contain a `TTechnicalImplementation` with `TBose` and `TSonos` being `TTechnicalImplementation`s?

Comment: Composition is your friend in this case, like @AndreasRejbrand already made an example for it.

Comment: Seems to me your inheritance tree is reversed. You should have a base `TSpeaker` that has the decendents `TBoseSpeaker` and `TSonosSpeaker`.

Comment: Ancestors of a class are static, determined and fixed at compile time. So, is what you ask for possible? No.

Comment: Or are looking at interface support like, ‘speaker support sonos and base protocol’. Then you should be defining a base TSpeaker class and depending on the actual speaker implementation (TSpeaker1 or TSpeaker2) add the interface ISonosSpeakerSupport and/or IBoseSpeakerSupport.